# Getting invalid_client error when trying to revoke an access token in Spring Authorization Server

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I am using **Spring Authorization Server 0.3.1** and calling **/oauth2/revoke** endpoint from OAuth client (angular-oauth2-oidc). Payload:

```
client_id: my-client-id
token: eyJraWQiOiJlYzA3N2Y2OC1jMjQ1LTQ[the rest is stripped for readability]
token_type_hint: access_token
```

Response contains error "invalid_client".
Several minutes of debugging show that exception is being thrown in org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.authentication.OAuth2TokenRevocationAuthenticationProvider#authenticate method:

```
    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        OAuth2TokenRevocationAuthenticationToken tokenRevocationAuthentication =
                (OAuth2TokenRevocationAuthenticationToken) authentication;

        OAuth2ClientAuthenticationToken clientPrincipal =
                getAuthenticatedClientElseThrowInvalidClient(tokenRevocationAuthentication);
```

getAuthenticatedClientElseThrowInvalidClient method:

```
    static OAuth2ClientAuthenticationToken getAuthenticatedClientElseThrowInvalidClient(Authentication authentication) {
        OAuth2ClientAuthenticationToken clientPrincipal = null;
        if (OAuth2ClientAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication.getPrincipal().getClass())) {
            clientPrincipal = (OAuth2ClientAuthenticationToken) authentication.getPrincipal();
        }
        if (clientPrincipal != null && clientPrincipal.isAuthenticated()) {
            return clientPrincipal;
        }
        throw new OAuth2AuthenticationException(OAuth2ErrorCodes.INVALID_CLIENT);
    }
```

It seems that OAuth2TokenRevocationAuthenticationProvider expects that passed **authentication** object will have OAuth2ClientAuthenticationToken in principal, but in fact principal is an instance of JwtAuthenticationToken.
As far as I understood since the call has a bearer token, it is authorized and JwtAuthenticationToken is set to SecurityContextHolder:

```
2022-06-28 23:27:01.392 DEBUG 16904 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /oauth2/revoke
2022-06-28 23:27:01.393 DEBUG 16904 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
2022-06-28 23:27:01.394 DEBUG 16904 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.s.o.s.r.a.JwtAuthenticationProvider  : Authenticated token
2022-06-28 23:27:01.397 DEBUG 16904 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] .o.s.r.w.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to JwtAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt@1615fb2d, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile, SCOPE_offline_access, SCOPE_email]]
2022-06-28 23:27:01.398 DEBUG 16904 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorized filter invocation [POST /oauth2/revoke] with attributes [authenticated]
```

Am I missing something? How can I get OAuth2ClientAuthenticationToken instead of JwtAuthenticationToken here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve the problem. It happened because I had **oauth2ResourceServer()** in the authorization filter chain settings (to enable userInfo endpoint) and sent a Bearer token in the header of /oauth2/revoke call:

```
@Bean
@Order(2)
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public SecurityFilterChain authorizationFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer<HttpSecurity> authorizationServerConfigurer = new OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer<>();

    RequestMatcher authServerEndpointsMatcher = authorizationServerConfigurer.getEndpointsMatcher();

    // Custom User Info Mapper that retrieves claims from a signed JWT
    Function<OidcUserInfoAuthenticationContext, OidcUserInfo> userInfoMapper = context -> {
        OidcUserInfoAuthenticationToken authentication = context.getAuthentication();
        JwtAuthenticationToken principal = (JwtAuthenticationToken) authentication.getPrincipal();
        return new OidcUserInfo(principal.getToken().getClaims());
    };

    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(ldapProperties.getUrl())) {
        http.authenticationProvider(ldapAuthenticationProvider());
    }
    http.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider());

    http
            .requestMatchers((matchers) -> matchers.requestMatchers(authServerEndpointsMatcher)
                    .mvcMatchers("/login**", "/saml2/**"))
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt) // to enable userInfo endpoint
            .apply(authorizationServerConfigurer)
            .oidc(oidc -> oidc
                    .clientRegistrationEndpoint(Customizer.withDefaults())
                    .userInfoEndpoint(userInfo -> userInfo.userInfoMapper(userInfoMapper))
            ).and()
    ;

    if (authProperties.getSso().isEnabled()) {
        http
                .saml2Login().successHandler(new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler()).permitAll()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement((session) -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED))
                .saml2Logout(Customizer.withDefaults());
    } else {
        http.formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll();
    }

    return http.build();
}
```

**So the solution is either to remove a Bearer token header or remove oauth2ResourceServer() in this particular filter chain.**
Also I found that as of now Spring Authorization Server supports only basic authorization for the /oauth2/revoke endpoint, and you cannot call this endpoint without specifying a client secret in the basic auth header. It's a problem when you have public clients. Keycloak for example provides an option to specify client credentials in the request body as well as in the basic auth header, and allows to omit the client secret parameter

Comment: Thanks. I saw you opened a GH issue as well. Unfortunately, I don't think it will be as simple as providing only the access token in the request without any client credentials, as there's a significant risk of abuse for leaked access tokens to be used to revoke access for legitimate clients. I'm not sure what Keycloak does to mitigate this risk, but SAS airs on the side of safety and currently requires client authentication in some form for this request.